# How can I get both alphabetized name and Kanji name from facebook API?

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I use python-social-auth.
I would like to get user's name from facebook.

If I write this, I can get Japanese name like "山田　太郎".

settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'locale': 'ja-JP',
    'fields': 'id, name, email', 
}
```

But I cannot get alphabetical name like "Tarou Yamada", I only get Japanese name and "太郎" is set in first_name field.
I want to get both.

And I know this way is not good becuase if a Spanish user registers, my application cannot obtain Spanish name.

If you give me some pieces of advice, I would be grateful.

Comment: You cannot get both via the API. You can only get the name based on the locale of your app.

Comment: Ah, really? Thank you for letting me know that. Thank you.